# Paragraph with multiple font colors vs. paragraph with an unset font color?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

In my Google Apps Script, I want to change the color of text only if the whole paragraph is already black. I can easily do this with:

```
if (currentPar.editAsText().getForegroundColor() === "#000000") {
    currentPar.setForegroundColor("#ffffff");
}
```

The problem I am having is that most black text in my document is technically unset, meaning that `currentPar.editAsText().getForegroundColor()` returns `null`.

I tried adding `|| currentPar.editAsText().getForegroundColor() === null` to the conditional, but it then would also return true for cases where multiple colors were used within the same paragraph.

Is there a way to tell the difference between the two cases of `null`?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal as follows.

- When the font color of all characters in the paragraph is `#000000`, you want to set the font color of the paragraph to `#ffffff`.
- For example, when the font color of a part of texts in a paragraph is not `#000000`, you don't want to change the font color of the paragraph.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- In the current stage, when the text is the default font color of `#000000`, `getForegroundColor()` returns `null`. And, it seems that even when a part of text in a paragraph is not the color of `#000000`, `null` is returned. (For example, when all characters in a paragraph are the same color like red, `#ff0000` is returned.) It seems that this is the current specification.
- In order to achieve your goal, in this answer, I would like to check the font color of each character in the paragraph using `getForegroundColor(offset)`.

When above points are reflected to the script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  DocumentApp
   .getActiveDocument()
   .getBody()
   .getParagraphs()
   .forEach(p => {
      const text = p.editAsText();
      let c = true;
      for (let i = 0; i < text.getText().length; i++) {
        if (text.getForegroundColor(i) != null) {
          c = false;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (c) {
        text.setForegroundColor("#ffffff");
      }
    });
}
```

#### Reference:

- [getForegroundColor(offset)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#getforegroundcoloroffset)

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the excellent Tanaike's answer I just found that this modification of his algorithm works a bit faster:

```
function myFunction() {
  DocumentApp
   .getActiveDocument()
   .getBody()
   .getParagraphs()
   .forEach(p => {
      const text = p.editAsText();
      const colors = text.getText().split("").map((_,i) => text.getForegroundColor(i));
      if (!colors.some(x => x != null)) text.setForegroundColor("#fffff");
    });
}
```

It looks counterintuitive. Loop with `break` should work faster. Probably the function `some()` is well optimized.